# Horizontal date picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, datepicker

I want to develop a date picker in flutter but with horizontal day, month and year selection. When I swipe left or right, I want the day / month / year in the center to be auto-selected. My current logic requires me to click the specific day / month / year to select it. Can someone help as to how can I achieve the desired result? Below is the design for my horizontal date picker.
[image]

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_timeline pub dev package and customize according my design. [2](https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_timeline)

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_center_date_picker Refer this.

Add this dependencies:horizontal_center_date_picker: ^1.0.0+2